# Media por grupos

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB"),
  col2=c(1060,8400,2060,9750),
  col3=c(100,800,200,950)
  
)
datos2$col4<-NA
```

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1  AAA 1060  100   NA
2  BBB 8400  800   NA
3  AAA 2060  200   NA
4  BBB 9750  950   NA
```

Quiero meter en la col4 la media de AAA y BBB según la col3

Calculo la media

```
aggregate(col3 ~ col1, FUN = mean, data = datos2)

col1 col3
1  AAA  150
2  BBB  875
```

Son 150 y 875 respectivamente. Meto el dato en el df

```
datos2$col4<-ifelse(datos2$col1=="AAA" , 150, datos2$col4)
datos2$col4<-ifelse(datos2$col1=="BBB", 875, datos2$col4)
```

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
1  AAA 1060  100  150
2  BBB 8400  800  875
3  AAA 2060  200  150
4  BBB 9750  950  875
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo más directo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas:

#### Mediante un `join` con `merge()`

Primero generamos un `data.frame` con las medias por cada grupo y luego simplemente "unimos" con `merge()` las dos tablas, la clave de dicha unión es `col1`, el grupo (`by`):

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("AAA","BBB","AAA","BBB"),
  col2=c(1060,8400,2060,9750),
  col3=c(100,800,200,950)
  
)

media_x_grupo <- aggregate(col3 ~ col1, FUN = mean, data = datos2)
colnames(media_x_grupo) <- c('col1', 'col4')
merge(datos2, media_x_grupo, by='col1')
```

---

#### A lo `dplyr`

Una forma sumamente clara de entender lo que se hace desde el propio código: agrupamos por `col1` y creamos un columna `col4` con `mutate()`,  con la media de `col3` y de cada grupo.

```
library("dplyr")

datos2 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col4 = mean(col3))
```